# Ruby Process.spawn significantly slows down execution of child process with big allocations

Tags: c, ruby, malloc

Ruby `Process.spawn` significantly slows down execution of child process with big allocations.

A minimal program where this occurs is the following C program compiled with `-O0`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 1024*1024*128;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        char *mem = malloc(n);
        memset(mem, 1, n);
        free(mem);
    }
}
```

When executing it as a child process through bash, or python, or C the execution takes 1.8 seconds.

But when using the following ruby script, it takes 5 seconds to execute:

```rb
Process.wait(Process.spawn("./a.out"))
```

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Edit: I've used ruby version 3.1.2p20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that [the reference ruby implementation turns off transparent huge pages (THP) on Linux](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/46e93ef53d66a73c1dbe317946dd4ac7d712bb1c/eval.c#L80). This setting is preserved across `execve()` as described in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html):

```
PR_SET_THP_DISABLE (since Linux 3.15)
              Set  the  state  of  the  "THP  disable"  flag for the calling
              thread.  If arg2 has a nonzero value, the flag is set,  other‐
              wise  it  is cleared.  Setting this flag provides a method for
              disabling transparent huge pages for jobs where the code  can‐
              not  be  modified,  and using a malloc hook with madvise(2) is
              not an option (i.e., statically allocated data).  The  setting
              of  the "THP disable" flag is inherited by a child created via
              fork(2) and is preserved across execve(2).
```

[Turning off transparent huge pages](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html#sysfs):

```
$ echo never | sudo tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

will make the runtime consistent.

Adding

```c
prctl(PR_SET_THP_DISABLE, 0 /* or 1 */, 0, 0, 0);
```

to the test program will also make the runtime consistent.

[The change that introduced this in ruby](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14705) probably did not consider that this setting is preserved across `execve()` and that it can thus have negative effects on big allocation heavy workloads in child processes.